# $_POST array sometimes skips numbers and IF statement ends

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I can not figure out how to print all $_POST array items (ending in successive numbers) if one or more numbers do not exist.  Not sure how to explain this... For example..

```
$i = 1; 
while( isset($options['item_code'.$i]) )
{
echo $options['item_code'.$i];
$i++;
}
```

This code works fine as long as the numbers continue to exist in order...

```
item_code, item_code1, item_code2, item_code3, etc...
```

But once a number is removed, the if statement stops and the rest of the values are not printed.  For example...

```
item_code, item_code1, item_code3, etc...
```

Will stop at "item_code1" because item_code2 does not exist.

I've tried solutions given to similar questions here on stackoverflow but they either do not work, do the same thing, or create a continuous loop.

I would appreciate any help that someone can give me here.

Comment: use a `foreach` loop

Comment: due to this being connected to a repeating block, the number and exact names (and number of items) are never known and therefore a foreach loop will not work. [unless I am missing something ...I don't want to be claim to know this for sure but not sure how that would work]

Comment: if that is the case then how would you know to code `item_codeX`etc?

Comment: you could be right.  trying to figure this out in my head to see how that would work in this particular case.

Comment: how is the `repeating block` generated? Is this a form with database driven content?

Comment: maybe if I elaborate a little ...there are other items in the options that do not repeat and the whole options array is called at once.  So if I use foreach, it will also cause the non-repeating items to repeat with the ones that are supposed to.   ...and yes, it is generated from wordpress options example.. $options = get_option($user->user_nicename . '_plugin_options'); and delivered in an array.

Comment: EXAMPLE: Array
(
    [fav_number] => 1
    [fav_color] => Black
    [item_code] => Test Item0
    [item_qty] => 0
    [item_remarks] => none
    [item_code1] => 
    [item_qty1] => 1
    [item_remarks1] => 
    [item_code2] => 
    [item_qty2] => 2
    [item_remarks2] => 
    [item_code3] => 
    [item_qty3] => 3
    [item_remarks3] => 
    [item_code4] => 
    [item_qty4] => 4
    [item_remarks4] => 
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it in wrong way. Please update your code like this. replace $i<=4 with number of element you want to trace

```
$key =  end(array_keys($options));
$dataa = explode('item_code',$key);
$count = $dataa[1];


$i = 1;
while( $i <= $count )
{
   if(isset($options['item_code'.$i])){
      echo $options['item_code'.$i];
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: as you are checking condition in the while loop so it will work for first true condition after that it will not execute

Comment: You seem to understand what I am going for here but your solution (although the closest) seems to cause two problems.  1) the skipped numbers in the variables can happen multiple times and can be as high as a few hundred at times.  2) I can not allow the $i to exceed the number of items because the last $i becomes the next number if adding additional blocks (in the repeater block on the form).

Comment: the you can count the number in array and pass that count instead of 4

Comment: Not sure how to do that if the number of the array is less than the last number of the item.  ....well just dawned on my how that might be able to be done but unfortunately I will need to use my brain on this one.  Maybe I can count the array and then subtract that from the last number in succession?  ok my brain hurts... gotta figure out what to do with the result.

Comment: yes correct I will let you know in a min. could you please mark this as answer with an upvote

Comment: selected and upvoted.  Awaiting your response.  thanks.

Comment: unfortunately that was worse.  Now it returns nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204919/discussion-between-amit-sharma-and-user2284703).

Answer (score 1):

I guess it can be done with an [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) functions:

```
<?php 

$codes = array_filter($options, function ($key) {
    return strpos($key, 'item_code') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

foreach ($codes as $code) {
    echo $code . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of while use foreach like

```
foreach($options as $option){
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: the $i has to be present in the solution because it's needed to append new number within form values ...and it's used when needing to add new blocks in a repeater block.